# What to use while presenting meeting?

Tags: sentence-construction

While addressing the meeting what should I use

A) I call this meeting to discuss on this issue.

B) I called this meeting to discuss on
This issue.

Why?

Comment: If it was you who arranged the meeting, you can use (B) to tell people why you arranged it (only you discuss an issue, you don't discuss on it). You could use (A) to request a discussion of an issue that has been raised at the meeting, but 'call upon' would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 6):

The most natural way to announce the purpose of a meeting that you called is:

> *I **have called** this meeting to **discuss** this issue.*

Note the *present perfect* tense, and no "on" after "discuss".

Present perfect works best here because we use it to talk about a past events where the present result is the important part. In your example, the present result is that we're all here now in this meeting.

Also, "discuss" is a *transitive* verb, which means it takes a *direct object* with no preposition, so "on" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

*"discuss **on**"* is incorrect usage.

it should be *"discuss this issue"*.

> I called this meeting to discuss this issue.

would be the more common/familiar way to say this.

> I call this meeting to discuss this issue.

is correct as well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

> I call this meeting to discuss on this issue

This sounds like you're announcing what you're doing in an official proceeding - like during a court trial or a government proceeding.

> I called this meeting to discuss on this issue

I think I'd modify this phrase to be:

> I called this meeting to discuss this issue

If you wanted to be more casual about it, you could use more conversational English like:

> Hey everyone! Thanks for coming. I called this meeting to talk about this issue because of this reason.

> Welcome everyone! This meeting is about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are using past or present tense, but using past tense is more natural, unless you have just called an emergency meeting.